# Windows активирует какой-то особый спящий режим

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

Сегодня утром переустановил винду на новую Windows Home (скачивал с оффициального сайта), и столкнулся с такой проблемой что если не двигать курсор, то спустя примерно минуту панель задач, курсор, иконки пропадают, а на их месте появляються обои. Я отключил спящий режим но проблема не решилась, но это пол беды, проблема в том что оно переходит в этот режим даже если запущено видео на ютуб или происходит какая либо другая активность. Видео с моей проблемой тут: https://youtube.com/shorts/o2Ut0RLLjCo
буду рад любой помощи

PS: извиняюсь за качество, если есть серьезная надобность в улучшении качества видео, могу его переснять

Answer (score 0):

Только что спонтанно нашёл решение своей проблемы пока копался по настройках в попытках все починить.
Решение которое мне помогло:
Настройки->Персонализация->Экран блокировки:

Снизу будет гиперссылка `параметры заставки`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в открывшемся окне в параметре заставка нужно выбрать `нет` и применить настройки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]